# Rails devise doesn't redirect to root path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

My `user` model looks like this in which `type` is column in `user` table and `std` is used just to get additional data at the time of user sign_up.Now when `user(type: Student)` login, devise again rendered the login page with message log in successful doesn't render the `root_path` and in log it is showing rollback transaction but when i refreshed the page then it render to `root_path`. This problem is only happening for `type:Student` and when i remove `validates_presence_of :std` line everything is running perfectly.

Now the question is why this is happening or how it can be done 
?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :std
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates_presence_of :type


  validates_presence_of :std , allow_blank: false , if: -> { type == 'Student' },
                         message: 'Student must add grade to continue'


end
```

Devise::RegistrationsController.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super
    if params[:user][:type] == 'Student' and user_signed_in?
      current_user.grade = Grade.new({cls: params[:user][:std].to_i})
      current_user.save
    end

  end

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :type, :std)
  end

end
```

Comment: use the `after_sign_up_path_for` devise method ([source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)#1-make-a-new-controller-registrations_controllerrb-and-customize-the-appropriate-method))

Comment: there is no problem in sign_up .. problem is happening in sign_in

Comment: devise also provides methods for sign_in ([here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)). hope it helps this time :)

Comment: getting this error now AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in Devise::SessionsController#create

Comment: the main problem is why this is happening because of that validation

Comment: you must overwrite the session controller, not the registration

Comment: Registration controller is  overwrite because I have added custom field type in devise table and attr_accessor :std to get data at the time of sign up

Answer (score 0):

Solved.. I think it is also validating `user(type:Student)`at the time of login so i just added

```
validates_presence_of :std , allow_blank: false , if: -> { type == 'Student' and new_record? },
                         message: 'Student must add grade to continue'
```

Now it is only validating at the time of signup only.